# Data does not save while calling persist() multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to persist to multiple entities. Sample code below:

```
public List<String> save(SalesInvoice salesInvoice, List<ClosingStock> closingStockList, Company company,
        Receipt receipt) {

    log.info("Saving Sales Invoice...");
    if (salesInvoice.getSalesChallanId() == null) {
        for (ClosingStock closingStock : closingStockList) {
            if (existingClosingStock(closingStock.getProduct().getId().toString()) == null) {
                em.persist(closingStock);
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
    em.persist(salesInvoice);
    receipt.setSalesInvoiceId(salesInvoice.getId());
    em.persist(receipt);
    return null;
}

// Edit: Add existingClosingStock method provided in comments

public ClosingStock existingClosingStock(String productId) { 
    try { 
        return (ClosingStock) em.createQuery("SELECT cv FROM ClosingStock cv WHERE cv.product.id=:productId") .setParameter("productId", productId).getSingleResult(); 
    } catch (NoResultException e) { 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Well, when I execute this query, the data didn't persist in database, but it shows the list of newly inserted data for small times, but data didn't save in database. I got no errors in console. Also put `em.getTransaction().commit();` before return does not work. When I tried persisting on single entity and put `em.getTransaction().commit();`, it worked perfectly. Like this:

```
public void save(Location location) {
    log.info("Saving Location.");
    em.persist(location);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Could you provide us the `existingClosingStock`method ? Have you tried in debug mode to check if it returns null to do the persist ?

Comment: you always need tx.commit (and tx.begin) to be compliant with the JPA spec, yet you aren't showing that. Then you have the log of your JPA provider to look at, to debug it

Comment: @Matthieu  public ClosingStock existingClosingStock(String productId) {
  try {
   return (ClosingStock) em.createQuery("SELECT cv FROM ClosingStock cv WHERE cv.product.id=:productId")
     .setParameter("productId", productId).getSingleResult();

  } catch (NoResultException e) {
   return null;
  }
 }

Comment: @Neil , i am injecting Entity Manager , i already did tx.begin().

Comment: Your code states that when you all em.getTransaction().commit(); it works perfectly - try using the same transactional scope you use in the method that works, by calling commit.  An EntityManager persist/merge do nothing until the EntityManager is told to synchronize with the database.  This is done with an explicit EntityManager.flush() or when the transaction itself commits.

Comment: @Chris , Thank you for your kind suggestions. Well when I tried commit the transaction after `em.persist(receipt);` , that also does not worked.

Comment: Other than the potentially adding new closingStock instances, and what ever receipt.setSalesInvoiceId does, what are the changes actually made in the persistence unit?  Are salesInvoice and receipt new instances, or did you mean to use merge instead?  What does your provider log show is happening when you call commit or flush?  Is the transaction you are calling commit on tied to the current entitymanager?

Comment: @chris, `receipt.setSalesInvoiceId(salesInvoice.getId());` simply set the id of sales invoice into receipt,yes  salesInvoice and receipt new instances. Not trying to merge, I am new to these things, Well Where should i put commit() or flush() the transaction?

Comment: You already said you tried calling transaction.commit() after the persist(receipt) call - so what shows up in your JPA provider log?  Also try calling em.flush() as it should throw an exception if it isn't tied to a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/), persist just schedules an [entity state transition](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/). The insert is executed during flush. If you don't commit the transaction, the flush will not be triggered automatically.

Anyway, you should always start a transaction, even if you plan to read data.